# I've seen 雄臭い used in some articles and posts but couldn't find the hiragana pronunciation, does anyone what it is?

Tags: kanji, pronunciation, readings, hiragana

Based on the kanji and what I gathered I'm assuming it means "smells manly" or "reeks of a man". The thing is I couldn't find any hiragana reading on the kanji and wanted to know if anyone knew how it's to be pronounced.

Answer (score 2):

It's おすくさい.

- -くさい is a kind of suffix that attaches to various nouns. See [this search result](https://jisho.org/search/*%E8%87%AD%E3%81%84) for common or idiomatic ones. This suffix is productive, and you can express "smelling of ～" by saying ～臭い. For example, 汗臭い ("smells sweaty"), 獣臭い ("smells like a beast"), トイレ臭い ("smells like a toilet"), and so on.
- 雄 as an independent word meaning "male" is read おす. See [this entry](https://jisho.org/word/%E9%9B%84). 雄臭い typically refers to animal-like body odor of males. Without any context, I would imagine the smell one would feel in an old locker room or a sumo wrestlers' training room. 男臭い refers to the same type of smell, but 雄臭い would sound more vulgar because おす/めす is mainly used with animals.

Answer (score 0):

I instinctively read it as otokokusai.
If you read each kanji they would read as osu (male) and kusai (smell) but I don't know if the word exist.
If you don't have the "い" it will read as oshushuu, use to refer to boar taint.

When I googled how to read the kanji you asked for, the search results were for 男臭い.

I think if the context is human, it is probably otokokusai and maybe osukusai when used for animals.